# Shortcut to Assign Multiple Foreign Keys Using Keyword CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Currently, I have the following code in my SQLQuery:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTable (
    OrderNumber varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    Date_Time datetime NOT NULL,
    WaitID varchar(7) NOT NULL,
    CashID varchar(7),
    TableNumber varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Order PRIMARY KEY (OrderNumber, Date_Time),
    CONSTRAINT FK_WaitID FOREIGN KEY (WaitID) REFERENCES WaiterWaitress(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CashID FOREIGN KEY (CashID) REFERENCES Cashier(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TableNumber FOREIGN KEY (TableNumber) REFERENCES RestTable(TableNumber)
);
```

I had to retype the `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES ...` three times. Is there a shortcut to this while still maintaining the ability to name the foreign key (i.e. `FK_WaitID`)?

Comment: Copy/paste?  Seriously?

Comment: @MJH I did use that, but is there a way to make it look a bit better? It's kind of repetitive according to me... Or is that the standard?

Comment: It is standard. You're not repeating anything, you're defining 3 different keys, against 4 different objects. Being a `FOREIGN KEY` is the only similarity

Comment: This is as concise a way as I know.  3 elements, 3 keywords.

Comment: I see. Thank you all! I thought that I was doing something repetitive and rather unnecessary.

Comment: Do you also want syntax like `varchar(7) columns { WaitID, CashID }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some sort of complicated script after you run the CREATE TABLE statement to add the constraints without repeating the actual keyword "CONSTRAINT", but that code will not "look a bit better".

Writing it this way keeps it clear for others in the future who may need to review the structure. The constraints and keys are clearly laid out, and that's really the way it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clarification! I didn't know that it's the standard, hence the question.

Comment: You can also just add the keys to the column definitions (e.g. - "WaitID varchar(7) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WaiterWaitress(ID)"), but what you have here is the better way to do it, I think.